# Do I need a protection diode to prevent reverse current flow into a voltage regulator?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, diodes

I have a 78L series voltage regulator that is used when a power supply is connected. When the power supply is absent, battery power is used. The battery will skip over the voltage regulator. The battery positive supplies power to the circuit at the same point as the voltage regulator output.

Do I need a reverse protection diode on the voltage regulator output to prevent damage to it when battery power is active and the regulator is not providing the power?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2famCiL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What kind of battery? Li-ions cannot accept more then 4.2V

Comment: Suppose you (do) place a diode between U1-Out and SW2-1 assuming you can tolerate a ~0.6Vf.  I once fried a linear reg due to reverse current and a diode fixed it.

Comment: Your schematic shows a 7805, but you refer to 78L- something. What is the type and voltage output of your regulator? A 7805 or 78L05 powered with 5V input will not regulate at all (other than provide some overload or short-circuit protection).

Comment: To summarize what shows in your question: (1) The 7805 requires "headroom." Your PSU, as shown, doesn't provide that headroom. So the 7805 won't work. (2) Your battery system shows a still lower voltage and most battery systems have drooping voltage as they discharge their energy, together with the 7805 meaning that the load needs to tolerate a very wide range of operating voltages. Without knowing more about your load, the arrangements simply look unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I was just asking about the diode at the output of the regulator. I couldn't figure out how to get the diagram to say something other than 7805. The voltages are not relevant for my original question about the diode.

Comment: Actually the output voltage may well be relevant when you are considering abusing the regulator. Vbe breakdown could damage it. The sloppier the question the less likely the answer is to be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LM7805 is basically an NPN Emitter Follower with feedback so removing the input makes the regulator high impedance unless you wish to block the ~4mA bias current .

You may verify my assumptions.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, no I do not need a diode. But adding one would prevent some current leakage to help improve the battery life?

Comment: Yes that’s correct but your regulator is not ideal as a LiOn charger and ought to be 3.7V. Which might be crudely what you get with 5V into a LM7805 where voltage drop out reduces from 2V as current drops to maybe 1.2V. Pls verify.

Comment: It will not be charging the batteries. Only powering the circuit when batteries are absent.

Comment: Ok then you will get unregulated 3 to 3.8V output.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with a diode just in case and to preserve some battery life. I'll just have to up the regulator to compensate for the diode voltage drop.

Comment: The regulator requirements depend on your load specs